# JavaScript Regular Expression For Years

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to ensure that the text of years is valid. The following are ALL valid years

- 2023
- 300
- -1
- 40AD
- 40 AD
- 3000 BC
- 200BC

Here is the Regex that I camp up with

```
^(-?)([0-9]+)\s*(BC|AD){0,1}$
```

However it has one shortfall. The above Regex also finds a match for the following:

- -200AD
- -700BC
- 0BC
- 0AD
- -0
- -0BC
- -0AD

So bascially, I do NOT want the Regex to find a match if any of the following happens:

1. A negative number is enetered, with the letters BC or AD
2. 0BC or 0AD should not be allowed
3. -0 should not be allowed. This also then includes -0BC and -0AD, which in turn should not be allowed either

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```js
let re = String.raw`
    ^ # begin
    (
        (
            # negative
            -
            [1-9] [0-9]{0,3}  # dont allow leading zeroes
        )
        |
        (
            # positive
            [1-9] [0-9]{0,3}  # dont allow leading zeroes
            (
                # AD/BC
                \s*
                (AD | BC)
            )?
        )
        |
        (
            # special case
            0
        )
    )
    $ # end
`

//

re = new RegExp(re.replace(/\s+|#.+/g, ''))

console.log(re)
;
`
2023
300
-1
40AD
40 AD
3000 BC
200BC
-200AD
-700BC
0BC
0AD
-0
-0BC
-0AD
`.trim().split('\n').map(s => s.trim()).forEach(s => console.log(s, re.test(s)))
```

Regular expressions are programs, why do people insist on writing them without spaces and indentation? ;)

Comment: Because I've never seen it done like that. It looks good

Comment: @DavePile Just do not do it on your own. There are some assumptions made by gog, so it is not generalizable.

Answer (score 2):

In the pattern that you tried `^(-?)([0-9]+)\s*(BC|AD){0,1}$` all parts are optional except matching 1 or more digits, so the pattern is a very broad match and is not taking any rules for zeroes or hyphens into account.

If you want a pattern for validation, you can omit the capture groups:

```
^(?:-?[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*\s*(?:AD|BC)|0)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-?` Match optional hyphen
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match 1-9 and optional digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*\s*(?:AD|BC)` Match 1-9, optional digits, optional whitespace chars and either AD or BC
  - `|` Or
  - `0` Match a single zero
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RPAq58/1).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot accept 2 answers. Yours is great as well. Both answers have different ideas that I like.

Comment: @Greeso No worries, that is perfectly ok!

Comment: @Greeso For the sake of future visitors, you'd better accept a safer solution, which is this. When regex newcomers start using fancy solutions, unnecessary questions arise and we have to help them out even more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

```
^(-?(?!0|0BC|0AD)[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]* ?(BC|AD))$
```

It ensures that there are no leading zeros, but with the exclusion of 0, 0BC, and 0AD, and handles the spaces before BC or AD. I tested it with the cases you provided in the post and it makes the correct matches.